# Phonegap installation using android studio

Tags: cordova

While making phonegap build using android studio showing error:

> Unable to load [Maven meta-data](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml).

Answer (score 0):

here is the procedure: after import project, select your folder for the hello project your created and then follow through all the default options.(remember to select Gradle)

then you will see the run button grayed out. what you have to do is go to edit configuration and then add a new android application, under general tab, select module as android and launch com.example.hello for activity. Then you can click ok.